# Unable to remove single or double quotes from txt file in Bash

Tags: bash, text, terminal

I'm trying to remove all punctuation from a text file, and decided to try to use this code:

```
$ cat file | tr -d [:punct:]
```

I also attempted with some added single quotes:

`$ cat file | tr -d'[:punct:]'`

and double bracketed

`$ cat file | tr -d[[:punct:]]`

While most of the punctuation is deleted from the text, the single and double quotes remain.  I tried just deleting the quotes with code like this:

```
$ tr -d \'\" file
```

but this also fails to remove the punctuation and takes out some random letters instead.
I would love to know how to resolve this error and ideally find a way to remove all the punctuation, including quotes, in one line.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
tr -d '[:punct:]' < file
```

Example:

```
echo 'Abc.!?#,"`'"'" | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

Output:

```
Abc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately when I run this command on the text file it does the same thing.  I believe the problem is actually in the kind of character I'm trying to remove, and will ask a new question to further specify.